# Properly remove entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I believe the following true about the way JPA works: when removing or adding a related entity to another entity (say, Employee to Department.employees), both sides of relationship has to be updated accordingly. That is, in a specific instance of removing Employee, I should not just remove it from EntityManager, but also remove it from referencing Department object. Failure to do so can result in other operations not working properly, like in this example with Spring Data JPA:

```
@Transactional
   public void test() {
       Function fn = repFun.findOne(75L);
       //at this point fn.tests = { Test{76} }
       doSomeDelegation(fn.getTests().iterator().next()); 
       fn.setName("new name");
       repFun.save(fn);
       repFun.flush(); // Whoa! "deleted instance passed to merge"
   }

  void doSomeDelegation(Test test) {
    repTest.delete(test.getId()); //in this example this will delete Test #76
  }
```

To do that, however, I will have to load a Department object, quite probably with its employee collection (which will result in yet another query unless it's eager-loaded), while otherwise I may have no need of that data in this transaction. More than that, there may be yet other entities referencing to this employee, so I will have to know all possible references (which is maybe justifiable but smells a bit), and to go thru them all, inspect ALL of objects on the referencing side (let's say there may be one or more Projects referring to this employee, then we will need to make a query to find all Projects actually referring to it, then go thru all discovered entities, load them with their references, and update those references).

That's quite a lot of work to do, and the most frustrating part is that it's actually not necessary to maintain a valid DB state! All right, if reference from Department to Employee would be a property mapped to a database column (i.e. Department.employee), not a collection, then nullifying this reference would be always essential; but if that reference is part of a collection, and a collection is essentially mapped to Employee rows, then removing Employee from DB would actually be enough to have a valid database. No need to update the Department, or to find and update multiple Projects. More to that: if such a Department is NOT in EntityManager, then we can still skip updating it, not screwing up JPA persistence! (not sure about version update, though).

One probable solution would sound like "knowing that there could be Department entities referring to the removed Employee, find only those of these which are already in EntityManager, and remove the employee from their referencing collections", but I don't think I understand how to do it, and, besides, that's a ridiculously complex logics to perform something as simple as deletion).

So, what's the right way to do it in the example above? It's really funny to observe how supposedly experienced developers cannot come up with a good answer to this very simple problem.

Comment: You are indeed responsible for the coherence of the collection of employees in the department. But if your use-case is "delete an employee", there is no department involved at all in this use-case, and you don't need to care about departments. Just delete the employee, and you're done.

Comment: Wrong, see the example. Of course, if we know for sure there is NO other logic in this transaction other than "delete by id", then you are right. However you cannot always be sure about that unless your application is especially trivial. In the example before, doSomeDelegation might even be a part of some other class. It might even not receive a target of removal as a parameter, but accidentally decide to delete this very object due to some isolated logic not related to that of test(). Since test() is not explicitly adding the same Test, there should be no conflict, - but it happens.

Comment: *Of course, if we know for sure there is NO other logic in this transaction other than "delete by id"*: well, you should know that. And if you know that departments and their list of employees are involved in the use-case that deletes an employee, then the use-case should make sure that coherence is maintained. The point is: it's the business logic responsibility. Not the responsibility of a low-level deleteById() repository method to maintain all possible associations.

Comment: OK I understand you answer, thank you. So I cannot use some my services as black boxes and instead have to know exactly what they do. That surely solves the issue but I cannot entirely agree with you in this. Hope to see other suggestions.

Comment: However I suppose even if I don't have to keep in mind everything that happens in each API call, I really have to refresh that knowledge anyway at the point when I am going to change something in one of methods, because there are other ways to introduce a conflict than stumble upon JPA restrictions. So maybe, maybe you are right after all.

Comment: But that would also mean that I cannot encapsulate parts of logic that
at some point execute removal (or maybe also some other actions) in such a way that those parts can be used in different sorts of transactions. Because the logic to maintain coherence - which I will have to put in that encapsulated fragments as well - would have to depend on other activity in the transaction (are we adding something as well? are we loading some Departments? etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It seems there is no way to automatically extract the entity from all referring collections already in EntityManager, without unnecessary loading of more entities. Barring, of course, EntityManager.clear()

2) This would make it more difficult to reuse doSomeDelegation() because it cannot predict what code will run in the same transaction. But, the calling code can predict that there may be interference with doSomeDelegation() - as long as it knows that doSomeDelegation(test) deletes an entity "test" (it should be part of method's contract, since "test" can be accessed by someone else - it's not something private to doSomeDelegation) *and* it works via JPA (this knowledge comes from knowing the environment and configuration).

3) So, the right way to write the above shown code is simply to know that doSomeDelegation deletes "test" via JPA and, because of JPA's contracts, this has to be accounted for in the calling code - i.e. fn.getTests().remove()

This (pt. 3) is obvious solution but I was suggesting that it's not right for calling code to have full knowledge of what is happening in a callee, but pt.2 explains why no full knowledge is required to be aware of relevant effects.

Answer (score 0):

There is such thing as reference in JPA. EntityManager has method `getReference`. This reference gives you the ability to do anything with entity without fetching any data but id. And if you need to delete referenced data — it will work in both cases of cascading — hibernate's and db's ones.

Comment: References will not solve the problem. I mean, look, we got entity A. Suppose A.b = some B. We can go from A to B without fetching B, true, but you cannot then delete A from B.a's without finally loading B. 'Cause, far as I know, accessing any proxy's method other than getId() will trigger loading the actual entity.

Comment: @MaksimGumerov but we can if we'll setup delete orphans as here: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/delete#Orphan_Removal_

Comment: Hmm. Orphans are entities which are no longer referenced by a relations' other side. If we extract Employee from Department.employees (without removing it from EM) and their relation is marked with orphanRemoval, the Employee becomes orphan and is removed, right? How does that help me to do exactly that thing - remove Employee from Department.employees?

Comment: @MaksimGumerov well, right now I suppose that I do not understand your task properly. What is your task exactly? To delete one concrete employee? Or to delete department if there is no more employees. Or delete employee from department without fetching information about it?

Comment: Suppose you want to write some helper function that does something that includes deleting one employee. How do you do that without loading its Department, if there is a chance there will be another persist() call with the same Department in this transaction.

Comment: I can see 2 probabilities:
1. I know id of employee
2. I don't know it.
If I know it — then the only thing which I need to do is to delete employee by id, which is totally possible with reference.
If I don't know it — then I should figure out which employee I need to delete by listing information about them. It is possible to list only needed subset os information with help of `SELECT NEW`, but anyways some information should be fetched.

Comment: This does not work. In the code example above, I know the test ID; and surely I can delete Test by its ID, which I do, but since there is no corresponding removal of this Test from a Function referring to it, the subsequent merge operation on that function fails. Of course, if the test() function knows that the deletion is coming, at can compensate for it on its side (only if there is but one Function for each test!), but that's the thing: what if it does not know that?

Comment: Or maybe you propose to use ID to delete Test from its Function's collection? This will require loading a Function. Granted, in this example the Function is already loaded anyway, but in general case the called function does not know that, and there be may some other Function also referring to same Test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164046/discussion-between-asm0dey-and-maksim-gumerov).

Answer (score 0):

Departments are the reference data. You should not control any related entities via `Department`. So you shouldn't have the `employees` association in the `Department`. It is the same thing as having the `users` association in the `Role` entity.

**if you still want to have the `employees` association**

1. Don't use any cascade for `employees`  at the `Department` part.
2. Don't consider *the session per request antipattern* or even *the persistent context pattern* as something unshakable. You can considr to use this approach: open the persistent context only for the simply CRUD operations like get or merge and work with entirely grapth of objects outside of the persistent context.

Comment: Well, using different persistent contexts is an option, but that way changes to one context will not be propagated to the other, right? So, if "doSomeDelegation" in my example does its work in separate context, it will not see changes accumulated in the outer context of "test" (they might not even be flushed yet!), and more than than: in some circumstances (depending on isolation level) "test" context will not see changes from "doSomeDelegation" either. That's bad, though sometimes acceptable.

Comment: Not using cascade - would work, but it's not right to globally change the model just to enable one specific operation, if the model is otherwise correct. And now to the question of "shouldn't have the employees association in the Department": why not? You say departments are reference data but they don't have to be. They might very well be master data, there may be accumulated statistics for them, relations between them, operations over them - same things that are true for employees. So why aren't they 1st class, and why they shouldn't have reverse relation to employees?

Comment: @MaksimGumerov _it will not see changes accumulated in the outer context_ — you shouldn't do any such changes in the context! CRUD operations are allowed only.

Comment: @MaksimGumerov _Not using cascade - would work, but it's not right to globally change the model_ — `cascade` is a Hibernate specific thing, this is not a model.

Comment: @MaksimGumerov _They might very well be master data, there may be accumulated statistics for them, relations between them, operations over them_ — other model classes can be used for that. These classes can have a relation to the `Department`.

Comment: @MaksimGumerov _So why aren't they 1st class, and why they shouldn't have reverse relation to employees?_ — Maxim, You will understand that, when you will work on a real project. :)

Comment: Oh, then probably during 5 years of my commercial Java career I never worked on a real project, what a pity.

Comment: @MaksimGumerov I meant a real project that uses Hibernate.